# Powerpoint manipulation - Add a slide at an index OR delete a slide

Tags: r, reporters, officer

I've been bouncing between two packages for my needs.
We make quite a few powerpoints at work, and I've been trying to automate the template, so all that's left to do is populate the template with data. 
We are pretty data heavy, and the actual content changes pretty drastically, so I'm just trying to create the template to start.

I've created a master template already, which has every possible slide that I would use. 
Then using either officer or reporteRs, I'm deleting/editing/creating slides based on the original template.

Basically, my master slide ppt has somewhere around 130 slides, and the real final ppt will have somewhere around 40 or 50 slides, depending on how many slides must be used.

So here's my question/issue -

If I'm using **officer** - 
Is there a way to create a slide at a specific index? I can find this functionality in **reporteRs**, but not in **officer.**

If I'm using **reporteRs** -
Is there a way to delete a slide? I can find this functionality in **officer**, but not in **reporteRs.**

I only need one of these to work for my issue to be solved, I just can't find either. If both of the packages could be used simultaneously, that would work just fine but that won't quite work for me either.

Thanks in advance,

Cody

Comment: There is no solution yet. One important point is that `ReporteRs` will be removed from CRAN the 16th of July. I have created an FR for your need https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/140

Comment: Understood, thank you for your reply and FR submission.