# Can officer re-order slides?

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

Here's the situation: I have a (corporate) Powerpoint template which contains the Master, a Title slide, and a "Closing" last slide.  I'd like to be able to use that as the basis for my work in `R` with `officer` , but don't see a way to reassign new slides to appear in between the existing default slides.   I was hoping either for a command like "add_slide" but with an option to set the index, forcing other slides to be re-indexed, or alternatively a way to edit the internal database used by `slide_summary`.
Closely-related issue [add slide at an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842445/powerpoint-manipulation-add-a-slide-at-an-index-or-delete-a-slide) .

Answer (score 1):

When released, the function `move_slide` will allow re-ordering of slides.  This is not as "beautiful" as a simple `add_slide( index = x,...)` implementation but will suffice so long as you keep careful count of the "builtin" slides in the template file.